# Multiple regressions with each factor level as contrast coding

Tags: r, regression, post-hoc, contrasts

I've determined there is a difference in factor levels on a dependent variable. I'd now like to determine which level differs from other levels. I know I can use contrast coding, specifically deviation coding (described [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION)) to compare each level against the grand mean. However, problems are:

1. Comparison of one level is against mean of means of remaining levels, ignoring group size differences
2. Contrasts are for j-1 groups, rather than all levels. I know this can be modified with additional coding specifications or computing estimated marginal means, such as by using emmeans.
3. Contrast comparisons use Wald-based t-statistics, whereas maximum likelihood-based methods may be more desirable in some cases.

To address above, I propose to dummy code each factor level as the contrast group, run a regression with this full model, and compare this model against a null model, with that group effect removed, using a likelihood ratio test.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Sample data, 4 groups of average different height
dat <- tibble(
  a_shortest_group = rnorm(1000, mean = 150, sd = 10),
  b_short_group = rnorm(1000, mean = 151, sd = 10),
  c_medium_group = rnorm(1000, mean = 152, sd = 10),
  d_tall_group = rnorm(1000, mean = 154, sd = 10)
) %>% 
  # Pivot to long format
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "group", values_to = "height") %>% 
  mutate(group = as_factor(group))
```

First, establish there is a difference amongst groups:

```
# Test for overall effect of group
lm_full_mod <- lm(height ~ group, data = dat)
lm_null_mod <- lm(height ~ 1, data = dat)
lrtest_output <- lmtest::lrtest(lm_full_mod, lm_null_mod) # or use anova
# Find significant overall effect
lrtest_output
... SIGNIFICANT RESULTS ...
```

Then I iterate through data, coding each level as the contrast group and compare dependent variable against remaining control group data.

```
# Iteratively dummy code each factor level as a contrast group to compare dependent variable of contrast group with remaining data
dat %>% reframe(unique(group)) %>% pull() %>%  # Get each factor level
  map_dfr(
    .x = .,
    .f = ~{
      # Dummy code as contrast group or control
      dat %>% 
        mutate(
          contrast_group = ifelse(group == .x, "contrast", "control")
        ) %>% 
      # Optional step- can add contrast group data back as a control group to truly get group mean
        # bind_rows(., dat %>% filter(group == .x) %>% mutate(contrast_group = "control")) %>% 
        {. -> tmp # tmp data for models
          lm_contrast_mod_full <- lm(height ~ contrast_group, data = tmp) 
          lm_contrast_mod_null <- lm(height ~ 1, data = tmp) 
          # Test models with contrast effect v. null model, pull test data with coefficient of interest
          lmtest::lrtest(lm_contrast_mod_full, lm_contrast_mod_null) %>% broom::tidy() %>% slice(2) %>% 
        add_column(height = as.character(.x), .before = 1) # Identify factor
        }
    }
  )
```

This produces:

```
  height         term        X.Df  LogLik    df statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 a_shortest_group height ~ 1     2 -14894.    -1     60.1  8.95e-15
2 b_short_group  height ~ 1     2 -14894.    -1      6.96 8.32e- 3
3 c_medium_group height ~ 1     2 -14894.    -1      4.76 2.92e- 2
4 d_tall_group   height ~ 1     2 -14894.    -1     67.5  2.10e-16
```

This gives results very similar to emmeans marginal means approach (p-value similar to hundredth):

```
emmeans::emmeans(lm_full_mod, specs = eff ~ group)$contrasts
```

```
 contrast              estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 a_shortest_group effect -2.119 0.271 3996  -7.822  <.0001
 b_short_group effect    -0.724 0.271 3996  -2.671  0.0101
 c_medium_group effect    0.598 0.271 3996   2.208  0.0273
 d_tall_group effect      2.245 0.271 3996   8.286  <.0001

P value adjustment: fdr method for 4 tests
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a known technique? Name? References?
2. Is this technique sound? Any foreseeable problems?
3. Are there any reasons why typical contrast coding, marginal means estimation (emmeans) is superior?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrt #2 on your list ('contrasts are for j-1 groups'), removing the intercept from the model specification is the usual fix for that problem.

Comment: Good point to handle this situation. I thought there might be situations where likelihood ratio test that can handle more than 1 df difference in models might not work for removing intercept, but that could probably be done in steps by removing intercept in multiple models.

Comment: Trying to use contrast codings to test specified effects in any but the simplest models is a losing battle.

Comment: Thanks, Russ Lenth. Yes, it seems limiting. In comparing my approach of fitting a separate model  for each factor level, with emmeans' least squares, the methods should be similar in simple cases like my example with normally distributed errors. I think in your code for emmGrid, you address some cases where they are different '# For some objects such as generalized linear models, specifying \code{submodel}
# will typically not produce the same estimates or type-2 tests as would be
# obtained by actually fitting a separate model with those specifications.'